# Spring Cloud Vault use local env variable when not in production for API Key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

I am using Spring Cloud Vault to store an API Key in production.

From reading the [spring.io blog](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/24/managing-secrets-with-vault) it appears I can use

```
 @Value("${apiKey}")
 String apiKey;
```

to access that key in vault.

This is fine when in production, but is there a way that I can set a default value/ some other way of setting up an apiKey that can be used locally for development? (preferably outside of vault if possible)

Comment: Just set it as an environment variable, or place it in the `application.properties` used locally, or pass it as an argument. Basically for the `@Value` to work it doesn't really matters where it comes from.

Comment: Thank you! In retrospect this seems obvious, unfortunately just had a mind block. 
If you post this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) several sources of configuration properties are consulted. It doesn't really matter where the value for `apiKey` comes from.

You have at least 3 options:

1. Set it in the environment,
2. Pass it as an argument with `--apiKey=<your-api-key>` when starting the application locally
3. simply place it in an `application.[properties|yaml]` used for local development.

Either way the `apiKey` property will be resolved locally without having to use the vault.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a default value (if the apiKey is not found ) like this :

```
@Value("${apiKey:MY_KEY_HERE}")
```

where `MY_KEY_HERE` is the default value.

Comment: In addition to that maintain your key locally in keystroke and pass it as environment variable or arguments like -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C://..//key-store.jks